# Material-ui Popover, Select, Menus componets positions come wrong, when i give zoom index

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

i give zoom index to my html, and after that Material-ui Popover, Select and Menus components which is use Material-ui Modal components, positions come wrong

Here is my İndex.css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
html{
    zoom:0.8
}}
```

My Js.

```
               <Popover
                anchorReference="anchorEl"
                open={Boolean(userMenu)}
                anchorEl={userMenu}
                onClose={userMenuClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'bottom',
                    horizontal: 'center'
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'center'
                }}
                action={refa}
                classes={{
                    paper: 'py-8'
                }}
            >
                <>
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('tr')}>
                        <img src="/assets/images/flags/tr.png" alt="tr" 
                         className="flag mr-8" />
                        <ListItemText className="pl-0 " primary="TR" />
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>
                        <img src="/assets/images/flags/en.png" alt="en" 
                         className="flag mr-8" />
                        <ListItemText className="pl-0" primary="EN" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </>
            </Popover>
```

Thats what should be [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUF5L.png)

But thats happen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRe6I.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, I have the same scenario and problem. Could you pls share your fix here. @Furkan

Comment: I couldn't find a solution, to fix this problem. but i fix my problem with  html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}. its work for me so I removed "zoom:0.8"